# Grails ExecuteQuery gives different resultset on select

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

My query

```
 def myQuery = PublicTraining.executeQuery("SELECT  t.id, t.isSoldOut, t.course.ebPrice, t.offerPrice FROM PublicTraining t Where exists (from t.course.tracks AS tracks where tracks.id IN (1) )")
```

which returns multiple record which is wrong

if i change it to

```
 def myQuery = PublicTraining.executeQuery("SELECT  t.id FROM PublicTraining t Where exists (from t.course.tracks AS tracks where tracks.id IN (1) )")
```

it returns the correct result set

why the selection of columns changes the result set here?

Comment: What happens if you run those queries in the management tool?  Also, you could try putting "logSql=true" in your DataSource.groovy to see what SQL is actually being created.

Comment: Can't write up an answer right now, but I think the result might actually be a multi-dimensional array (with one level representing columns and another representing rows). Is the length of the array returned by your first query 4?

Answer (score 1):

1. Both the queries will return multiple records.
2. You cant predict the order since you are not applying not sort order.
3. 1st query will return List of List of 4 elements, whereas 2nd query will return just List of id values